# external javascript undefined display

Tags: javascript

I'm currently a noob in javascript and i've been experimenting some stuff.
What i'm doing right now is i'm trying to display numbers from 1 to 10 using an external js
that i created. But when i run in it always displays the "undefined" text at the bottom

here is the external js:

```
function increment(count){
while(count<10){
document.write(count +"<br>")
count++;
}
}
```

here is my script in html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title> javascript </title>
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="ok2.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
document.write(increment(3));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

is there any way to eliminate that "undefined" display at the bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change in your HTML like below....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title> javascript </title>
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="ok2.js"> </script>
</head>
<body>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
increment(3);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You do not need to write `document.write();`

Comment: oops yeah i forgot to edit it sorry, but still there is an undefined display at the bottom when i run the script >_<

Comment: @user3169490 Your page and external .js file are located in same folder of root..?

Comment: @user3169490 could you please make sure your .js path for `src="ok2.js"` ?

Comment: yes they have the same folder. the script is running perfectly. it displays all numbers from 1 to 10. but there is an "undefined" display at the bottom of the last number.

Comment: Please include the full code because the increment function you posted didn't output an undefined..